# Generate json from a Map

Tags: json, hive, bigdata, objectmapper

I have a class like this :

```
    Public class person {
    private String name;
    private String city;
    private Map<String,Object> mapOfColumns;}
```

I am trying to generate a json from Map of Person objects and I am using Object Mapper for it.

```
    Map<String, Person> personMap;
    objectMapper.writeValue(g, personMap.values());
```

where g is JsonGenerator.

Following json gets generated:

```
[{"name":"Mansi", "city": "x", "mapofColumns":{"key1":"value1", "Key2":"value2"}}]
```

My problem is that I want to generate something like:

```
[{"name":"Mansi", "city": "x", "mapOfColumns_key1":"value1", "mapOfColumns_Key2":"value2"}]
```

so that I can read this data through dremio or hive for querying it as I want to query individual elements of mapOfColumns as well. Also, the keys in mapOfColums values are not fixed in this map. There could be a few of the 550 keys present at a given time so I don't want to pre define any schema. I want something like Object Mapper where I don't have to define schema before hand because I don't want to store null values for hundreds of elements of mapOfColumns values.

I am trying to use custom serializer but I am not sure if I am on the right path. Thanks in advance!